# Чи варто вживати вислів "точка зору"?

Tags: вибір-слова, словосполучення, калька

Наткнулась на таке [обговорення](http://perekladach.blogspot.com/2012/04/blog-post_26.html):

> Про "точку зору"
>   Часто натрапляю на вислів "точка зору". Востаннє зауважив такий вислів на сайті радіо "Свобода" (http://www.radiosvoboda.org/section/columns/681.html).  Вочевидь, що тут маємо справу з калькою з іноземних мов, як-от: point of view або точка зрения. Очевидно, що українською мовою такий вислів слід перекладати словами: погляд або думка. Тож надалі використовуймо замість кальки "з моєї точки зору" правильний український вислів "на мій погляд" тощо.

Напротивагу, на цьому ж ресурсі користувач прокоментував дане твердження:

> Гадаю, ця проблема значною мірою надумана. :) Звісно, ніхто не сперечається, що "точка зору" є запозиченням, перекладним кліше. Але, по-перше, такий вираз справді існує в інших мовах; по-друге, його поширення в мові українській пов'язане із незворотним процесом абстракції терміну "точка", який історично розійшовся з цілком конкретним словом "крапка" десь, мабуть, на початку ХХ ст. У минулому столітті вираз "точка зору" в значенні "погляд", "позиція" вже спостерігається у словниках (напр., Вирган і Пилинська, 1959) та вживається українськими класиками:
>   - "І коли взяти до уваги точку зору Ірини Леопольдівни, то багато сільських десятикласників залишиться поза вузами." (Григорій Тютюнник.)
>   - "І клумба ця, і латка асфальту виникли завдяки настійливості Лукії Назарівни і мають з її точки зору значення принципове." (О. Гончар.)
>   - "Автор, стоячи на тій точці зору, що проблема перекладу — лінгвістична проблема... ігнорує... особливості художнього перекладу." (М. Рильський.)

Таку позицію прочитала на [Онлайнкоректор](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B0/):

> Замініть скалькований вислів точка зору на стилістично правильний варіант: думка, погляд.

Також Олександр Авраменко у своїх [відео-уроках](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cY_XvbxW1n8&list=PLpjP6nb03Z4k5Wdj8qOj3s_o49a0f9qxX&index=7) пропонує вживати *погляд, замість *точка зору*.*

Але [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/zir) містить вислів *точка зору*:

> Точка (кут) зору — певний погляд на що-небудь, особисте ставлення до чогось. Багато спеціалістів дотримуються тієї точки зору, що хвіст і плавці є основним рушієм дельфінів та інших китоподібних (Знання та праця, 1, 1966, 6)

То ж чи справді потрібно вилучити цей вислів зі свого мовлення, чи, все-таки, він має право на існування?

Comment: Цікаво, що з СУМ-20 цей вислів вилучили: у статті [«зір»](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=36307&page=1146) було «точка (кут) зору», стало «кут зору».

Comment: Мене постійно цікавить чому точка, а не крапка?

Comment: @СеверинСавчук, на мій погляд, сучасна різниця між цими словами така: крапка — це результат застосування чорнил або фарби на якійсь поверхні (а також похідні поняття); точка — це абстрактний математичний об'єкт нульового розміру (а також похідні поняття).

Comment: Так, саме "на мій погляд", "на мою думку", "на мій розсуд"...

Comment: Це запитання не має жодного сенсу, оскільки ви самі наводите у своєму ж запитанні декілька авторитетних або офіційних джерел, що підтверджують що цей вислів варто вилучити зі свого лексикону згідно офіційних правил української мови, фактично відповідаючи на власне питання, однак при цьому чомусь запитуєте чи варто. Я б особисто закрив це питання

Answer (score 1):

Фразеологічний словник української мови

В статті [ЗІР](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53399/357949.html) містить лише приклад ***кут зору***

> **кут зо́ру.** Певний погляд на ті чи інші явища, певне розуміння чогось,
>   певна позиція в чомусь. *У кращих творах першої збірки В. Симоненка вже
>   є вагома поетична думка, певна позиція, свій кут зору на описуване* (З
>   журналу). під **куто́м зо́ру** яким, чого. *Світову філософію художник
>   засвоює для того, щоб розглядати явища дійсності під іншим кутом зору*
>   (З журналу).

Разом з тим в статті [ТОЧКА](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53410/361850.html)  цього ж словника української мови присутній  приклад:

> стоя́ти на **то́чці зо́ру** якій. Поділяти певні погляди,
>   дотримуватися якоїсь думки, відомих уявлень тощо. *Автор, стоячи на
>   тій **точці зору**, що проблема перекладу — лінгвістична проблема, ..
>   ігнорує .. особливості художнього перекладу* (М. Рильський).

[Вікіцитати](https://uk.wikiquote.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83)

> **Точка зору** (англ. point of view, POV) — життєва позиція, з якої суб'єкт оцінює всі події навколо нього. Термін походить від «точки
>   зору» — місця, де знаходиться спостерігач і від якого залежить видима
>   ним перспектива.

В СУМ-20

> [ЗІР](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=36307&page=1146) Кут зо́ру *див.* кут;
>
> [КУТ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=46339&page=1462)  (12) Кут зо́ру – певний погляд на ті чи інші явища, певне
>   розуміння чогось, певна позиція в чомусь.

Хоча СУМ-20 не містить виразу ***точка зору***, на мою думку даний вислів має право на існування.

Comment: Не може бути "кут зору", але може бути "кут огляду".

Answer (score 1):

Менѣ стало цѣкаво, відки вираз *точка зору*.

На жаль, менѣ не вѣдомі українські етімолоґічні збірники, тому на поміч приходе анґлійська на мережевому етімолоґічному збірнику [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/point%20of%20view):

> **point of view**
>
> "position from which a thing is or is supposed to be viewed," 1727, translating French [*point de vue*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/point_de_vue#French), a loan-translation of Latin *punctum visus*. Figurative use "state of mind, predisposition (conscious or not)" is from 1760. The Latin phrase was translated into German as [*Gesichtspunkt*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gesichtspunkt#German).

Тож звідси можна зробити щонайменше два висновки:

- То справдѣ калька, першоджерело скорѣш за все — латина. Яким чином і коли сюди потрапила? Не знаю, треба копатися наприклад в корпусах, але, як *на мій погляд*, це не головне тут.
- Вираз справдѣ [поширений](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/6947/585) помѣж европейських мов.

Тому тут все відносно просто: якщо не соромите ся кальок, то вираз має права на існування, а тому можна вживати. Або ж навпаки.

Ще один цѣкавий факт. Відповѣдно ЕСУМ, [*точка*](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0#23239), що явно не належе одній москівській, є прямим семантічним відповѣдником до *punctum*:

> *То́чка* «графічний знак; цятка; (мат., фіз.) місце, що не має виміру; пункт»
>
> - за семантикою аналогічне лат. punctum «точка» при pungere «колоти»;
> - [*точ(в)точ*] «точно» Нед, р. точь в точь «тс.»;
> - псл. [tъčька], похідне від *tъčь «тс.», пов’язаного з *tъknǫti/tykati «ткнути, тикати»;
> - пор. первісне значення – «місце, куди ткнули, слід від протикання»;
> - р. болг. м. *то́чка* «точка», бр. [*то́чка*] «радіоточка», п. ст. tecz «точка», ч. tečka, схв. та̏чка, слн. tóčka, с.-цсл. *тъчька* «точка»;

Декотрі мови, в тому числѣ наша, розрізняють *точка* і *крапка*, а декотрі і часто — нѣ. Приклади:

- анґлійська, де [*point*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/point#etymonline_v_17537), що прямо від згаданого *pungure*, проти *dot*, *period*, *full stop* ітд.
- польська: [*punkt [widzenia]*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/punkt_widzenia#Polish) проти *kropka*.

Тож тут теж нічого дивного і лоґічно, щонайменше менѣ, чому тут саме *точка*, що є калькою до *punctum*. Тут менѣ стало навѣть цѣкаво: відки взявся *кут*.

---

Іще, СУМ-20 [насправдѣ](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/4186/585) мѣсте вираз *точка зору*, навѣть згаданий в окремій виносцѣ, просто чомусь в гиншій статтѣ — про [приіменника *з*](https://sum20ua.com/?page=1145&wordid=36193):

> // У сполуч. зі сл. *погляд*, *точка зору* і т. ін. уживається при вказуванні на предмет, зміст, спрямованість чиїх-небудь думок, оцінок і т. ін.
>
> > *“Біла Пустеля” майже безфабульна річ – з погляду критика тридцятих років* (Ю. Яновський); *В природі багато ще загадкового .. з точки зору сучасних наук* (О. Гончар); *З погляду поступу наукового Дмитро Іванович не був середньою людиною* (Ю. Мушкетик).

Answer (score 0):

Ще знайшов такий варіант:

> На перший погляд здається, що вислів точка зору є калькою відповідного російського словосполучення. Але це не зовсім так. І російське стале словосполучення точка зрения, і українське точка зору, як вважають вчені-етимологи, — це переклад відповідних висловів із європейських мов.
> *— Надія Сологуб ([джерело](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine70-36.pdf))*

Comment: Шчос̃ стат̃̄а надто бе̂дна. Можна було би наприклад навести ті ж во̂дпове̂дні вислови. Але, так, шчонајменше анґліјс̃ка маје такиј висло̂в: [point of view](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/point-of-view), про шчо вже згадано в запитан̃̄е̂.

Comment: Низькоякісна відповідь.